AWS CLI: Authenticating Docker CLI to default registry
I am trying to upload an image using ECR, to do so I am following these steps.
But when doing so, I get this error message:
.Password was unexpected at this time.
Is there another command that can be run in order to authenticate and proceed? I do have the AWS CLI installed already as well.
I am on Windows therefore I am trying to run this command:
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com 

Are you running that in an normal windows command prompt? Or in Powershell? That looks like a Powershell command.

I've tried both the command prompt and powershell, but still no luck. I believe it is a powershell command though.

Yes that's a powershell script, and requires the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell to be installed. If you don't have that or know what that is, you should be following the AWS CLI instructions instead.

After doing some digging, this command seems to resolve the issue:
Install-AWSToolsModule AWS.Tools.ECR
Afterwards, the original command should work as expected.
